# Function evaluation timed out error in Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm using framework 3.5. I have one group Linq syntax like below

```
 var TmpClause = (from c in MES_WO_Tracking
                         join s in WorkOrders
                         on c.WoNo equals s.OrderNum
                         where s.Plant == "XX" && c.Shift != null
                         group new { 
                             c.QtyComplete,
                             c.QtyScrap
                         }
                         by new
                         {
                             MRP = s.MRP_CTLR,
                             SeqNo = c.SeqNo,
                             TriggerSAP = c.TriggerSAP,
                             Shift = c.Shift
                         } into n
                         select new BkdKPIOutput
                         {
                             MRP = n.Key.MRP,
                             SeqNo = n.Key.SeqNo + n.Key.TriggerSAP,
                             Shift = n.Key.Shift,
                             OutputQty = n.Sum(c => c.QtyComplete.Value),
                             InputQty = n.Sum(c => c.QtyScrap.Value) + n.Sum(c => c.QtyComplete.Value)
                         });
```

It always give me the "Function evaluation timed out" error. But strange thing is that I check the native sql, it only spend 1 sec.

```
SELECT  [t2].[MRP_CTLR] AS [MRP] ,
    [t2].[SeqNo] + [t2].[TriggerSAP] AS [SeqNo] ,
    [t2].[Shift] ,
    [t2].[value] AS [OutputQty] ,
    [t2].[value2] + [t2].[value3] AS [InputQty] FROM    ( SELECT    SUM([t0].[QtyComplete]) AS [value] ,
                SUM([t0].[QtyScrap]) AS [value2] ,
                SUM([t0].[QtyComplete]) AS [value3] ,
                [t1].[MRP_CTLR] ,
                [t0].[SeqNo] ,
                [t0].[TriggerSAP] ,
                [t0].[Shift]
      FROM      [MES_WO_Tracking] AS [t0]
                INNER JOIN [WorkOrder] AS [t1] ON [t0].[WoNo] = [t1].[OrderNum]
      WHERE     ( [t1].[Plant] = 'XX' )
                AND ( [t0].[Shift] IS NOT NULL )
      GROUP BY  [t1].[MRP_CTLR] ,
                [t0].[SeqNo] ,
                [t0].[TriggerSAP] ,
                [t0].[Shift]
    ) AS [t2]
```

Does anyone know this? Very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first selecting all data into TmpClause then in another variable do the group clause on the TmpClause data. Although this is not Ideal it might help you find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Jethro, I tried your way, it still gave me the same error on group linq query. At last, I tried to select all data convert to AsEnumerable() first, then group the data base on the Enumerable variable. That works. Still not sure where is the problem. Anyway, thanks for your idea.